# ssl (https) for https://my.example.com resolves to https://example.com ip address

Tags: nginx, ssl, subdomain

I have a server my.example.com with ip address 111.111.111.222
I have a server example.com with ip address 111.111.111.111

I created an ssl certificate with letsencrypt for my.example.com

However, when I try to connect to https://my.example.com it resolves to the ip address of example.com

Do you have any suggestions how I can properly configure a ssl certificate for a subdomain hosted on a different ip addresss?

Comment: That has nothing to do with an SSL certificate. You're describing a DNS problem.

Comment: I have the A record set at my dns provider to resolve the correct ip address to my.example.com That works great. Is there another record I should put to redirect the https?

Comment: Your A record points your IP to your domain or vice versa?

Comment: yes. the non ssl works http://my.example.com

Comment: please post the real domain name

Comment: http://erp.gopts.net